# About read-only transaction in PostgresXL

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xl

my PostgresXL version 9.2.0

(1)
After I started the GTM, DataNode, Coordinator, as well as the coordinator of each datanode postgresql.conf archive

```
#default_read_only_transaction = "off" modified default_read_only_transaction = "off"
```

(2)
Use the following instructions to connect information nodes:

```
psql -h 192.168.20.138 -p 25431 -U postgres
```

192.168.20.138 is the first data node ip location.

25431 is the first data node postgresql.conf set port settings.

postgres is installed PostgresXL system account, also a super manager of this PostgresXL.

(3)
Establish a database using the following command:

```
create database "MyTest";
```

The following error message has appeared:

can not execute CREATE DATABASE "MyTest" in a read-only transaction.

How can I be able to cancel the read-only transaction of this restriction?

THX.

Answer (score 2):

You should connect to coordinator for creating database. If you connect to datanode, all operations are restricted to read-only.